# How to see what calls return using browser console

Tags: console

I am working on an ethernaut CTF (screenshot below). I am using the browser console to interact with the contract (seen at the right in the image). How can I use the console to at least see the result of my calls to flip? My theory was that blockValue/FACTOR was always going to round down to 0 and therefore I could solve this by calling contract.flip(1) 10x, but based on what I can see on etherscan, I'm not right. But I can't see what flip is returning on etherscan.

Can I use something like await contract.flip(1) and then console.log the return?

[image]